# Recommended spacing between the figure and caption

Tags: floats, captions, koma-script, subfloats, subcaption

I am using a template based on Koma-script. The vertical spacing between any float object (table and figures) and the caption is very close (Idk the default value). Hence I would like to increase the vertical spacing. What is the recommended vertical spacing between:

a) float and caption ?

b) subcaption and caption?

c) subfloat and subcaption?

Comment: Maybe post the code of the template, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: Note that \abovecaptionskip is larger than \belowcaptionskip (which is usually 0pt).  Various packages and document classes have different ways to deal with this WRT tables (caption is generally above the tabular).  What I find annoying is the space below subcaptions when there are more than one row.  I like to add \vskip\floatsep (space added between floats).